# pg query in javascript not recognizing postgis geomtype POINT

Tags: javascript, prepared-statement, postgis

I'm having problems running a query that works directly in psql with postgis extension but not with the javascrip pg library connection within a prepared statement.

The query that runs and writes in the database is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO waps(bssid, strength, "location")
VALUES('T_601', '100', ST_GeomFromText('POINT(38.70722651513132, -9.15248591105515)', 4326));
```

The table waps has the location column as geometry type.

In my college javascript project I have this section of code returning an error:

```
        let sql = "INSERT INTO waps (bssid, strength, location) VALUES($1,$2, ST_GeomFromText(POINT($3),4326)) RETURNING id";
        let wapId = await pool.query(sql, [bssid, strenght, location]);
```

`location` receives ex: `"38.70722651513132, -9.15248591105515"`, and returns an error:

```
{ error: function point(unknown) is not uniqueupLog Completed in 2ms
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (project/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (project/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (project/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.stream.on (project/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
  length: 195,
  name: 'error',
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42725',
  detail: undefined,
casts.',
  position: '76',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'parse_func.c',
  line: '572',
  routine: 'ParseFuncOrColumn' }
```

So why does the query in psql runs normally but when prepared in a javascript environment throws an error?

The problem lies, normally, between the screen and the chair, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like quotes are missing around POINT

Comment: I faced palm a little hard after seeing this comment, yes, it was missing the quotes.... But after that, the prepared statement failed binding the parameters, I had to put the POINT function outside and attach attributes before generating the prepared statement, it works!